# Obj-C - didSelectRowAtIndexPath not firing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm stumped. For some reason, when I tap my tableView cell, didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not executing? And yes, my tableView delegate is set, and data is populated in the cell label. Am I missing something obvious from my below? Essentially, when my user taps the tableView cell, the contents of the cell label should appear in a textfield.

**.h**

```
@interface RegisterViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {

}

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

**.m**

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.tableView.hidden = NO;

       self.tableView.delegate = self;
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    }

- (void)LoadJson_search{

    searchArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //    NSLog(@"str......%@",strSearch);
    // This API key is from https://developers.google.com/maps/web/
    NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=%@&key=AIzaSyAm7buitimhMgE1dKV2j4_7doULluiiDzU", strSearch];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str1];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error=nil;
    if(data.length==0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary *jsondic= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        //         NSLog(@"1,,,,%@",jsondic);
        [searchArray removeAllObjects];
        if([[jsondic objectForKey:@"status"]isEqualToString:@"ZERO_RESULTS"])
        {

        }
        else if([[jsondic objectForKey:@"status"]isEqualToString:@"INVALID_REQUEST"])
        {
        }
        else
        {
             for(int i=0;i<[jsondic.allKeys count];i++)
            {
                NSString *str1=[[[jsondic objectForKey:@"predictions"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"description"];
                [searchArray addObject:str1];
            }
            self.tableView.hidden = NO;


            //            NSLog(@"%@", searchArray);
        }
        if (searchArray.count == 0) {
            self.tableView.hidden = YES;
        }else{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
   // if (self.addressField.tag == 3) {

    if (textField == self.addressField) {

        strSearch = [self.addressField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        if([string isEqualToString:@" "]){

        }else{
            [self LoadJson_search];
        }}
        // }
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField{
    self.tableView.hidden = YES;
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    return YES;
}



        -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
            return 1;
        }


        -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
            return searchArray.count;
        }


        -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
            if(!cell) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
            }

            cell.textLabel.text = [searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            return cell;
        }


        - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

            NSLog(@"TAPPED CELL");

            self.addressField.text = [searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            self.tableView.hidden = YES;
            [self.tableView reloadData];

        }
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping the code into a `DispatchQueue.main.async` to make sure it's executed on the main thread?

Comment: I know you mentioned it but double check you have both the `dataSource` and `delegate` set on the tableview. The issue you describe is exactly what would happen if the `dataSource` is set but the `delegate` is not.

Comment: Yes - does not work :/ @LukasWürzburger

Comment: There's not enough to go off here. All we could do is guess. Is the table interaction enabled? Is the table view's `allowsSelection` true?

Comment: Is the table view Selection option in Storyboard set to `No selection` by any chance?

Comment: @surToTheW Nope :/ So bizzare. And every other tableView I have inside my app works just fine.

Comment: @CraigSiemens See edit above. Definitely set.

Comment: I'd use the view debugger at which point you can confirm (a) that the delegate is still what you think it should be; (b) that there’s nothing in front of the table view that might be consuming the touches; (c) that selection is still allowed; (d) that overall user interaction is allowed; etc.

Comment: If the delegate was wrong, data wouldn't populate either @Rob? User interaction is allowed, selection allowed...and nothing is in front of the tableView.

Comment: @Brittany - No, the population of the table view is dictated by the data source, not the delegate. You have to set both of those. Plus, you could of had something that was omitted from the question that was affecting it later on. The view debugger is “where the rubber hits the road”, showing you the properties of the table view (and the entire view hierarchy) at runtime, rather than relying upon what we think we did in the code and/or IB.

Comment: Captured view hierarchy - literally nothing stopping the tableView from being selected. In fact when I tap the view, the cell turns grey but the log I have in didSelect is never called. @Rob. Added more code/context to how I'm populating the tableView above.

Comment: That’s a good data point, namely that the tableview is actually accepting the user interaction, which eliminates a lot of possible issues. So, when you select the table view in the view debugger and you look at the table view’s properties in the “object inspector”, the delegate is set there, too? I assume it is, but there are some edge cases where it might not be. Again, assuming it’s OK, this is all very curious. We’re rapidly approaching the “rebuild it from scratch” stage and/or create copy of project, rip out everything unrelated, and upload it somewhere like github where we can review it.

Comment: Seriously @Rob... this is nuts. Ha ha. The only difference between this tableView and every other one in my app is that my other tableViews use custom cells... this one just uses a default cell. I'm stumped.

Comment: BTW, that’s a testable thesis, namely make it a custom cell. I wager that’s not the issue. But, we can’t help you until we can reproduce the problem. I know it’s frustrating. Sorry. ;(

Comment: Wow...after hitting my head against the wall for countless hours, I finally figured out what's wrong. There's a UITapGesture inside my ViewController (tap was added to self.view) and it was keeping me from tapping my tableView. That is hell. Is there anyway to keep my tapGesture and still have didSelectRow work? @Rob

Answer (score 0):

Try with the next line in your viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.allowsSelection = YES;
```

Or check that property in your storyboard. Well you can try with the cell too like this:

```
// This line do not affect the selection delegate only the style    
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; 
cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Tried it...no dice :(

Comment: Let me try your code in a new project and I will notify what I found :)

Comment: The same code works very well for me, maybe in your story board you have a wrong property, please show the properties of the IB object

Comment: Wow how strange... okay, will double check properties. Stand by :)

Comment: So crazy - I built it again in a brand new ViewController from the ground up and I still cant get didSelectRow to execute. Are your delegates both set to self (the view controller)?

Comment: Wow...after hitting my head against the wall for countless hours, I finally figured out what's wrong. There's a UITapGesture inside my ViewController (tap was added to self.view) and it was keeping me from tapping my tableView. That is hell. Is there anyway to keep my tapGesture and still have didSelectRow work?

Comment: Yes, you need to use the shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: method.